# Is that why Doberman came to the console?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```js
var dogs = {
    Fido: "Mutt",
    Hunter: "Doberman",
    Snoopie: "Beagle"
};
var myDog = "Hunter";
var myBreed = dogs[myDog];
console.log(myBreed); // "Doberman"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a key value relationships in objects in JavaScript. this means that you can access the value (in this example "Doberman") by using the key (in this example "Hunter").

There are mainly 2 ways to access the values of the object. Either by using

```
object.key
```

or

```
object[key]
```

On the above example you used the second.

Answer (score 0):

What's your question? Why `Doberman` is output?

Well, JS you can read object properties as arrays or maps, where you indicate the "key".
For every property into the object, the name is the key, so your object `dogs` has keys: `Fido`, `Hunter` and `Snoopie`.

Now, you have another value stored into `myDog` variable. When you do `dogs[myDog]` is equal as `dogs["Hunter"]`.

And as I've explained before, you can use the key to acces the value object.

In this case, the value for `Hunter` is `Doberman`.

This is why ouput by console.